# Зачем в стандартных методах обязательно выбрасывать throws?

Tags: servlet, java-ee, java

Здравствуйте! Недавно приступил к изучению `Java Servlet` и возник такой вопрос: почему в  стандартных методах многих интерфейсов все устроено так, что обязательно надо выбрасывать `throws`, например:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws  ServletException, IOException {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поправочка: не "*надо обязательно выбрасывать*", а "*можно выбрасывать*". Ключевое слово `throws` в объявлении метода означает, что этот метод может (но не должен) выбрасывать перечисленные исключения. Не путать с инструкцией `throw`, которая непосредственно выбрасывает исключение. Ключевое слово `throws` нужно, чтобы код, вызывающий этот метод знал, какие исключения могут возникнуть в процессе его работы, и мог перехватить и обработать их.

Answer (score 1):

немного дополню ответ fori1ton.
В данном случае исключения объявленные в методе - это контракт этого метода, т.е. да бросать эти исключения вовсе не обязательно, а точнее лучше не нужно если на то нет причин.
Этот контракт говорит Вам, чего от Вас ждут в случае исключительной ситуации. Т.е. если что-то пошло не так, то вы сообщите системе: "я сломался" и система сможет как-то адекватно поступить в этой ситуации.

Если Вы бросите что-то не входящее в данный контракт, например какой-нить SQLException (например если Вы работаете с БД и что-то случилось), то система скорее всего не сможет адекватно это воспринять, этого от Вас не ожидают. В таком случае данные исключения нужно отлавливать и либо самому делать что-то с этим, либо привести к указанным исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что ТС не почень понимает что для чего служит trows (в первом ответе вс написално), суть в том что вы регестрируете какие исключительные ситуации вы можете перехватить.

А теперь напшу по простому: Если у вас в методе возникает исключительная ситуация которая зарегестрирована (написана) после trows, то вы можете не перехватывать её в этом методе (не писать блок try catch), после этого вам следует перехватвать исключительтную там где метод вызывается (там и будет try catch).
private int a = 2;
private int b =0;

public int doSomthing(){
int result;
try{
result = a/b
} catch (e someException){
System.out.println("деление на 0")}
return result;}

Здесь вы перехватываете исключительную ситуацию тамже где она возникает.
Теперь немного перепишем:

//теже a & b;

public int doSomthibg() trows someException {
if (b==0) {throw new someException();}
return a/b}

public class someClass{

какой-то метод вызывающий метод в которм возбуждается исключительная ситуация{
try (
какой-тоОбъяект.doSomthing)
catch (e someException){
System.out.println("деление на 0")}
}
}
Вообщем это ключевое слово позволяет вам пробрасывать исключительную ситуацию дальше, не обрабатывая её в момет возникновения